# Bootstrap JavaScript with Gulp

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, sass, gulp, gulp-sass

I'm new to gulp and want to add bootstrap to my project.
I already added SASS Bootstrap. That was no problem because I found a good documentation. Now I also need to add the javascript of bootstrap to my project.
I tried to follow  [this](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) documentation and added just the API to my index.html at the end of my body.
Like this:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

But I wont work. Do I have to include the bootstrap.js in an extra js? Just like I importet bootstrap.sass to my main.sass?

I can't find a good documentation and don't know what to do now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you have to import bootstrap.js as well. It is important that you import that in the head of your HTML.

Answer (score 3):

Check out this setup guide for configuring Bootstrap Sass using Bower and Gulp.

> [Setting up Gulp, Bower, Bootstrap Sass, & FontAwesome](https://ericlbarnes.com/2014/09/19/setting-gulp-bower-bootstrap-sass-fontawesome/) (Barnes, Eric L.)

You should compile all your CSS (including third-party libraries) into one minified CSS file. Saves bandwidth (and loading time) and makes it harder for people to reverse engineer your websites.

#### Bower

```
bower install bootstrap-sass-official --save
```

```js
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp":           "3.9.1",
    "gulp-bower":     "0.0.13",
    "gulp-notify":    "3.0.0",
    "gulp-ruby-sass": "2.1.1"
  }
}
```

#### NPM

```
npm install gulp gulp-ruby-sass gulp-notify gulp-bower --save-dev
```

#### Gulp

```js
var gulp   = require('gulp'),
    sass   = require('gulp-ruby-sass'),
    notify = require("gulp-notify"),
    bower  = require('gulp-bower');

var config = {
    sassPath : './resources/sass',
    bowerDir : './bower_components'
}

gulp.task('bower', function() {
  return bower().pipe(gulp.dest(config.bowerDir))
});

gulp.task('css', function() {
  return gulp.src(config.sassPath + '/style.scss')
    .pipe(sass({
        style: 'compressed',
        loadPath: [
          './resources/sass',
          config.bowerDir + '/bootstrap-sass-official/assets/stylesheets'
        ]
      })
      .on("error", notify.onError(function(error) {
        return "Error: " + error.message;
      })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/css'));
});

// Rerun the task when a file changes
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch(config.sassPath + '/**/*.scss', ['css']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['bower', 'css']);
```

#### Sass

```scss
/*
 *  File: style.scss
 */
// Import Bootstrap
@import "bootstrap";

// ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. I added it as you said and it works. 
But when I use JS on my html it don't look likes the samples in the documentation. (http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-examples)
I copied the code and the button looks like this because of the working SASS. But the modal not. It looks like a normal modal without any bootstrap. 
How can I fix that? I put the two tag (tags in my question) at the end of my body. Is that enough?